# How to Rename Column Headers in R

Tags: r

I have two separate datasets: one has the column headers and another has the data.

The first one looks like this:
[image: columnheader dataset]

where I want to make the 2nd column as the column headers of the next dataset:

[image: dateset]

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `colnames(df2) <- as.character(df1[[2]])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you seen our [Best practices guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can use `colnames`, which is a list of your column names of your dataframe or matrix. You can rename your dataframe then with:

`colnames(df) <- *listofnames*`

Also it is possible just to rename one name by using the [] brackets.
This would rename the first column:

`colnames(df2)[1]  <- "name"`

---

For your example we gonna take the values of your column. Try this:

```
colnames(df2) <- as.character(df1[,2])
```

Take care that the length of the columns and the header is identical.

---

Equivalent for rows is `rownames()`

Answer (score 1):

dplyr way w/ reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 11:15)
df_n <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = c("col1", "col2"))
names(df) <- df_n %>% select(y) %>% pull()
```

I think the `select() %>% pull()` syntax is easier to remember than list indexing. Also I used `names` over `colnames` function. When working with a dataframe, `colnames` simply calls the `names` function, so better to cut out the middleman and be more explicit that we are working with a dataframe and not a matrix. Also shorter to type.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

`names(data)[3]<- 'Newlabel'`

Where `names(data)[3]` is the column you want to rename.