# Replacing column headers with matched variables from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, header, tidyverse

I have a data frame with around 50 entries and 2 columns - long list of short question names and corresponding long question names:

| variable_short | variable_long |
| --- | --- |
| cat | Do you have a cat? |
| col | Is blue your favourite colour? |
| stress | Are you stressed at work? |

This is the summary of questions used in a survey. The survey responses are in a separate dataframe containing the column names which are the variables in variable_short -

| person.id | cat | col | stress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2567 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I am trying to create a new dataframe with only the 10 questions I need from 50 and the corresponding survey responses along with the person id. What I am struggling with replacing the short question format in the survey data with the corresponding long question format from the variables data frame. Ideally something like this:

| person.id | Do you have a cat? | Are you stressed at work? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2567 | 1 | 1 |

I started to subset to get the variables to the ones I need:

```
new <- subset(variables, variable_short %in% c('cat', 'stress'), select = c('variable_short', 'variable_long'))
```

It reorders the variables so I can't go by the order and I assumed this isn't the most efficient way to do it incase variable order changes. I can rename column headings but I am not familiar yet with matching especially matching corresponding variable to a header.

I am completely stuck right now so any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would suggest using `tidyr::pivot_longer` to convert your survey data in long, "tidy" format, then do a left_join with your lookup table using the survey short name as key, then pivot wider again.

Comment: Are you looking to create a separate table for each person.id with just the headers that pertain to them, or a big table with all the person.id's but many NA' columns relating questions which were not asked of that particular person.id?

Comment: @Jon Spring Thank you for your suggestion, I will just try that. I am essentially trying to create the third table which will just be altering the second table to keep all the data but replacing the headers except 'person.id' with selected variables from the variable.long from the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rename the column names using `match` :

```
names(df2)[-1] <- df1$variable_long[match(names(df2[-1]), df1$variable_short)]
df2

#  person.id Do you have a cat? Is blue your favourite colour? Are you stressed at work?
#1      2567                  1                              0                    1
```

If you want to keep only the values which has 1 in it, reshape the data in long format and `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -person.id) %>%
  filter(value == 1)

#  person.id name                      value
#      <int> <chr>                     <int>
#1      2567 Do you have a cat?            1
#2      2567 Are you stressed at work?     1
```

Comment: The 'match' function works perfectly, I think that's what was needed. I will also check out 'pivot_longer', it might be a better way to structure the data. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You problem may be that R does not allow column headers with spaces to be referenced later in the code, so using the long question as a column title would not be a successful strategy. To avoid this in my own coding, I replace each space with an underscore for easy readability, but I've seen other people use camelCase or PascalCase naming styles. Since you only have ten questions / column titles, this may be an okay situation to hard code the new column names rather than rename automatically, as detailed in [this Stack Overflow question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687741/how-to-rename-column-headers-in-r).